# How to disallow certain string values for a variable or object property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

We can allow only certain string values for object property in TypeScript like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
    paramA: 'valueA1' | 'valueA2';
    paramB: 'valueB1' | 'valueB2';
}
```

I'm trying to define paramC to accept any string value except certain string values, something like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
    paramA: 'valueA1' | 'valueA2';
    paramB: 'valueB1' | 'valueB2';
    paramC: string except ('valueC1' | 'valueC2' | '');    // I know syntax isn't correct but it should deliver the idea of what I'm trying to do
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, because [negated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) never made it into the language, there's no way to write this as a specific type.  The best you can do is to make `MyInterface` generic like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQV37N), but I'm not sure such a complication is worth it to you.  What are your use cases?